# What's the background and meaning of this philosophy quote?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, quote

I'm new here and this is my first question. My professor gave me an assignment that let me choose any philosophy quote and talk about it. I want a quote that sound COOL so I go to Google and search it a bit and see a lot of cool quote but mostly I don't understand about it so I can't really write anything about it at all so I choose nothing. Some days ago I watch a youtube video and see one long quote in the comment section

> *The man who sought blood saw only his own. The man who sought power was betrayed by his follower, The man who sought answers gained only new questions, The man who sought peace was left restless, The man who sought recognition was forgotten. The man who sought a family was abandoned. The man who sought prestige was humbled.*

( The video I watch is about an anime call Fate/Zero, and of course this anime has a lot of nice quote ) I want to choose it but I want to know some background about it, like maybe some famous philosophy in the past have said it before so I could talk more about it ( I'm not really good at paragraph writing at all so I need some references ). I'm not going to put the whole thing just one phrase from those seven and I think I prefer "*The man who sought answers gained only new questions*" the most. But anyway, I'd go to the other phrase which have more material as it would help me understand more deeply into it ( I'd also appreciate it if you could give me the idea of the quote above too ). Thank you very much for taking your time!

Comment: Wait, why I can't say hello or greetings everyone? I edited it a few times but it doesn't appear in my text

Comment: Are you sure that's more than just lyrics of an OST song translated? I'm not. That's not philosophy, that's pop culture.

Comment: What did your prof mean by philosophy quote? I mean... I'd take that to mean a quote from a philosophy text. "The man who sought answers gained only new questions" is nice and seems relevant to the problem of knowledge in philosophy. (Knowledge isn't certainty... or certainty is far too ambitious a goal). Descartes sought certainty, but I think he failed. Munchausen trilemma seems tp prevent certainty. So knowledge is something less... Maybe you could work on something like that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certainty        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma

Comment: @AmeetSharma yes it is sth like that. I think I might say it wrong in English. I'll take a look on that one. Thank you, sir!